# Sum Cells with Same Date, and Groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract information from a .csv file generated by thingspeak.com. The following is a snapshot of my .csv file titled "feeds.csv"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJbqd.png

The "field2" column are just values of 1, representing minutes. I want to add all the "field2" values to the same date (which I have done).

I have already successfully been able to parse the date and add the "field2" values related to the date using the groupby function.

The new .csv file generated is shown in the link below. Where Stations is the "field1" values, and "Time (minutes)" is the sum of "field2" values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA4FZ.png

However I want the "Station" column to be the Station for a particular date. Right now it is just counting the number of entries under "field1".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("feeds.csv")

df.created_at = df.created_at.str.split(' ').str[0]  
dfout = df.groupby(['created_at']).count()
# dfout2 = df.groupby('field1') #Experimenting (ignore for now)

dfout.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
finaldf = dfout[['created_at', 'field1', 'field2']]
finaldf.columns = ['Date', 'Station', 'On Time (minutes)']

finaldf.to_csv('insertnewname.csv', index=False)
```

The output should be as follows (shown in the link below):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LdmL.png

I know using the .count() simply adds the number of rows (and not sum) of the field2 values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I am a noob at this stuff, so any explanations to help explain the additional code would go a long ways.

Comment: Btw, one friend advice - [Rather don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) - check also  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can change your solution by add column `created_at` to `groupby` and specify column `field2` for aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("feeds.csv")

df.created_at = df.created_at.str.split().str[0]  
finaldf = df.groupby(['created_at', 'field1'], as_index=False)['field2'].sum()

finaldf.columns = ['Date', 'Station', 'On Time (minutes)']

finaldf.to_csv('insertnewname.csv', index=False)
```

Another solution working with datetimes - first add `parse_dates` parameter to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for converting, so possible pass to `groupby` [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("feeds.csv", parse_dates=['created_at'])

finaldf = df.groupby([df['created_at'].dt.date, 'field1'], as_index=False)['field2'].sum()

finaldf.columns = ['Date', 'Station', 'On Time (minutes)']

finaldf.to_csv('insertnewname.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm, I appreciate it. Will give your solution as accepted answer.